# Python: How to annotate text with dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Apple FRU
Banana FRU
Copenhagen LOC
London LOC
Mango FRU
Orange FRU
Zurich LOC
```

Saved as a txt file (eurofruit_dict.txt)

I also have another .txt file (eurofruitsalad.txt) where there is a text, where every sentence is written in a different line. Kind of like this:

```
There is a rotten apple in London.
He ate a banana in Zurich.
```

1. I need to write a program, where with my dictionary, I need to annotate the text. And save it as a separate document.
2. I also need to mention how many names of fruits and cities were in the text.
   Kind of like:

   ```
   Number of fruits in the text: 
   Number of cities in the text:
   ```

I have gotten this far:

```
with open("eurofruit_dict.txt") as fd:
  for line in fd:
    (key, val) = line.split()
    dictionary = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in fd)
```

I don't know what to do from here.

Now I'm a new to programming, so please be kind to me. Moreover, I missed my lectures in the last two weeks because I caught pneumonia.

Comment: You are creating a new dicitonary in each line, instead of updating the existing one. (Remove the for loop and just use the list comprehension.) Was this your problem, or is there another question?

Comment: This sounds like homework, so we're not going to solve it for you... however, remember that in python, `string` objects have a `replace()` method that operates as such: 

`"I love Paris".replace('Paris', 'Berlin') => 'I love Berlin'`